# What is self-action in quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, action, interactions

I read that the gravitational field in any quantum theory will be self-acting. What does it mean? How can a field interact with itself?

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I don’t remember ((it was a long time ago. But if I misunderstood, tell me please.